# How to parse a JSONString and turn its values into an Array?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

How to parse a JSONString, from a once JSONString.stringify simple array that now "appears flattened" inside, and turn its values back into a Java List or Java Array? (Using Jersey 1.x & Java) ?  Array originally started as [1,2,3] before it was stringify-ed.

items = (3) ["            To", "8357", "30028"] --> JSON.stringify(items) sent through rest call

Chrome Dev Tools's Request Payload after rest call:
items=%5B%22%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0To%22%2C%228357%22%2C%2230028%22%5D

```
/*inside (Jersey) Rest Resource
@POST
@Path("/...")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response receive(@Context SecurityContext securityContext, @Context 
HttpServletRequest srequest, String jsonString) throws URISyntaxException, 
JSONException ...
```

/*eclipse watch on jsonString inside (Jersey) Rest Resource
items=%5B%22%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0To%22%2C%228357%22%2C%2230028%22%5D
*/[enter image description here][2]

NOTE: There is no name value.  There is no entity.

There's only a very simple string of IDs because that's all I need.  (Is that supported by Jersey 1.X or JAX-RS 1.X?)

```
JSONArray jSONArray = new JSONArray(java.util.Arrays.asList(jsonString));
```

> Eclipse jSONArray Expression:   jSONArray
>   --myArrayList
>   ----elementData
>   ------[0]  "items=%5B%22%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0To%22%2C%228357%22%2C%2230028%22%5D"
>
> ----------value
>   ------------[0..99]
>   ---------------[0]  i
>   ---------------[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neS7G.png)  t
>   ---------------[2]  e
>   ---------------[3]  m
>   ---------------[4]  s
>   ---------------[5]  =
>   ---------------[6]  %
>   ---------------[7]  5
>   ---------------[8]  B   ....

Comment: Use a search engine and look for "Java+JSON processing". Or what have you done? I can't see any code from you and processing JSON in Java is really basic.

Comment: please see edited specifics

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand exactly your original question, but one of the way is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonParser {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    File f;

    static String fn = "";
    static String js1 = "{\"name\": \"LALA\", \"email\": \"tst@tst.com\"}";
    String name = "name";
    String email = "email";
    String fName = "firsName";
    String city = "city";
    // ... other needed fields
    User u1 = null;

    public JsonParser() {
        parseFile();
        System.out.println("\n" + u1.toShortString());
    }

    private String openFchooser() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException, Exception {
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        return f.getAbsolutePath();

    }

    // To parse JSON files with data
    //===========================================
    public void parseFile() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            // To parse obj 1
            Object obj1 = parser.parse(js1);
            System.out.println("User 1: " + obj1.toString());
            System.out.println();

            JSONObject jobj1 = (JSONObject) obj1;
            String from_name = jobj1.get(name).toString();
            String from_email = jobj1.get(email).toString();
//            String from_fName = jobj1.get(fName).toString();
//            String from_city = jobj1.get(city).toString();
            u1 = new User(from_name, from_email, null, null);
//            System.out.println(u1.toString() + "\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JsonParser();
    }

    class User {

        String name = null;
        String email = null;
        String fName = null;
        String city = null;

        public User(String n, String e, String f, String c) {
            this.name = n;
            this.email = e;
            this.fName = f;
            this.city = c;
        }

        public String getFirsName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String setFirsName(String s) {
            return this.name = s;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public String setEmail(String s) {
            return this.email = s;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "{\"name\":" + this.name + ", "
                    + "\"email\":" + this.email + ", "
                    + "\"firsName\":" + this.fName + ", "
                    + "\"city\":" + this.city + "\"}";
        }

        public String toShortString() {
            return "{\"name\": \"" + this.name + "\", "
                    + "\"email\": \"" + this.email + "\"}";
        }
    };
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
User 1: {"name":"LALA","email":"tst@tst.com"}


{"name": "LALA", "email": "tst@tst.com"}
```

Comment: please see my edited detailed client and server side specifics

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  I managed to find an alternative send & receive:

now sending array without stringify-ing it first 
receiving with:
    public Response archiveSelectedApplicants(@Context SecurityContext securityContext, @Context HttpServletRequest srequest,
            @FormParam("items[]") List items) throws URISyntaxException